# How to scrape a web page with aspx code using VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping

I'm trying to automate the download of the tarifs of this web page.

https://app.cfe.mx/Aplicaciones/CCFE/Tarifas/TarifasCREIndustria/Tarifas/DemandaIndustrialSub.aspx

```
Sub DescargarTarifasCFE()
Dim IE As InternetExplorer
Dim HTMLDoc As HTMLDocument
Dim URL As String
Dim FechaINI As Date, FechaFIN As Date, Fecha As Date
Dim HTMLSeleccionar As HTMLSelectElement

Application.Calculate

Application.StatusBar = False

FechaINI = Sheets("Base").Range("FINI").Value  'asignamos a las variables los valores de las fechas
FechaFIN = Sheets("Base").Range("FFIN").Value

For Fecha = FechaINI To FechaFIN

    If Day(Fecha) = 1 Then 'filtro la acción cuando el dia sea 1 ... de esa manera solo hago una entrada ...    

        URL = "https://app.cfe.mx/Aplicaciones/CCFE/Tarifas/TarifasCREIndustria/Tarifas/DemandaIndustrialSub.aspx"
        Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
        With IE
            .navigate URL
            Do Until .readyState = 4: DoEvents: Loop
        End With
        IE.Visible = True
        Set HTMLDoc = IE.Document

        Set HTMLSeleccionar = HTMLDoc.getElementById("ContentPlaceHolder1_Fecha_ddAnio")

        HTMLSeleccionar.Value = Year(Fecha)

    end if

next fecha
```

I am able to change the year, but this action hasn't got the same result as if I do direclty through the web. I think that in the second case some code is executed. The problem is I don't know how to replicate this action through VBA.

Comment: This is an excellent first question +

Answer (score 0):

You need to fire the onchange event

```
HTMLSeleccionar.FireEvent "onchange"
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to use a [css attribute = value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors) selector to target the right year option. The following includes a check as to whether it is already selected.

You can see the parent `select` id and the child `option` tag `value` attributes here:

[image]

This:

```
.querySelector("#ContentPlaceHolder1_Fecha_ddAnio [selected]").Value
```

returns the correctly selected year by first finding the parent `select` element by [id](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/ID_selectors) `#ContentPlaceHolder1_Fecha_ddAnio`, then using a [descendant combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Descendant_combinator) `" "` and [`\[\]`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors) attribute selector to find the selected option within.

This:

```
.querySelector("[value='" & CStr(año) & "']").Selected = True
```

constructs the desired attribute = value selector e.g.

```
[value='2018']
```

---

VBA:

```
Option Explicit

'VBE > Tools > References: Microsoft Internet Controls
Public Sub GetData()
    Dim ie As Object
    Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    With ie
        .Visible = True
        .Navigate2 "https://app.cfe.mx/Aplicaciones/CCFE/Tarifas/TarifasCREIndustria/Tarifas/DemandaIndustrialSub.aspx"

        While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend

        Dim año As Long
        año = 2018   '<== Year(Fecha)
        With .document
            If .querySelector("#ContentPlaceHolder1_Fecha_ddAnio [selected]").Value <> año Then
                .querySelector("[value='" & CStr(año) & "']").Selected = True
            End If
            Stop 'delete me later

        End With

        .Quit
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: I'm afraid this code doesn't change the selected value. This is the result I have ...![code](https://ibb.co/RpxgG7g)

Comment: I tested it and it works. I will have another look.

Comment: I just ran it again. It works perfectly. Did you run exactly as shown above?

Comment: i've just tested and the result is the same ... it doesn't work

https://ibb.co/kyhcKw6

Comment: Don’t know why we get different results. I’ll add another solution later.

Comment: I can send you a gif if it working but it won’t change that it doesn’t work for you for some reason.